# Certificate file ldap-server.crt does not exist

Tags: shibboleth

when I tried **Single Sign** on to the **wso2 API manager** using the **shibboleth IDP** as the federated Identity provider,

a login error occurred as

> ldap-server.crt doesn't exist.

Can you give me any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not much aware of `Shibboleth IDP` however i have used other SSO's and what i did was to import the certificates `.crt` in `client-truststore.jks` file.So have you tried importing the certificate `ldap-server.crt` in `client-trustore.jks` file .Hope this gives you an idea